# How to print cheque using crystal report?

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I got a problem here. I am printing continuous cheque using crystal report. My cheque Height is 8.9 cm and Width is 27.9 cm. When I am printing using crystal report then it exports nicely to PDF but when I want to print it on the cheque it is printing on different position. The printer is a Dot Matrix BP-9000 E Aui Printer. Is there anyone who can suggest me what I can do to print this content in the proper place?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the page margins before printing.

```
        CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins PageMargins1 = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins
        {
            topMargin = 250,
            leftMargin = 250,
            rightMargin = 250,
            bottomMargin = 250
        };

        Report1.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(PageMargins1);
```

The above values are arbitrary. Try modifying them so you can get the desired result for your printer.